# TIdHTTP Get Method showing weird characters while loading xml file (Not showing russian chars)

Tags: c++, xml, c++builder

I am using TIdHTTP to download xml file (currency values) from url: http://nbt.tj/?c=4&id=28&lg=ru&d=21-02-2011&export=xmlout and it showing me weird characters

here is my code

```
UnicodeString s =serv->Get("http://nbt.tj/?c=4&id=28&lg=ru&d=13-10-2009&export=xmlout");
cxMemo1->Text=s;
```

I tried to set TIdHTTP charset property to windows-1251 but it's all the same
here is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>
<ValCurs Date="13/10/2009" name="Êîòèðîâêè âàëþò óñòàíàâëèâàåìûå åæåäíåâíî">
 <Valute ID="036">
   <CharCode>AUD</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Àâñòðàëèéñêèé äîëëàð</Name> 
   <Value>3,9651</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="944">
   <CharCode>AZN</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Àçåðáàéäæàíñêèé ìàíàò</Name> 
   <Value>5,4526</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="826">
   <CharCode>GBP</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Àíãëèéñêèé ôóíò ñòåðëèíãîâ</Name> 
   <Value>6,9160</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="051">
   <CharCode>AMD</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>100</Nominal> 
   <Name>Àðìÿíñêèõ äðàìîâ</Name> 
   <Value>1,1353</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="971">
   <CharCode>AFN</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>10</Nominal> 
   <Name>Àôãàíñêèõ àôãàíè</Name> 
   <Value>0,8816</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="974">
   <CharCode>BYR</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>100</Nominal> 
   <Name>Áåëîðóññêèõ ðóáëåé</Name> 
   <Value>0,1598</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="981">
   <CharCode>GEL</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ãðóçèíñêèé ëàðè</Name> 
   <Value>2,6111</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="208">
   <CharCode>DKK</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Äàòñêàÿ êðîíà</Name> 
   <Value>0,8680</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="784">
   <CharCode>AED</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Äèðõàì  ÎÀÝ</Name> 
   <Value>1,1926</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="840">
   <CharCode>USD</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Äîëëàð ÑØÀ</Name> 
   <Value>4,3806</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="978">
   <CharCode>EUR</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>ÅÂÐÎ</Name> 
   <Value>6,4705</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="356">
   <CharCode>INR</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>10</Nominal> 
   <Name>Èíäèéñêèõ ðóïèé</Name> 
   <Value>0,9428</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="364">
   <CharCode>IRR</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1000</Nominal> 
   <Name>Èðàíñêèõ ðèàëîâ</Name> 
   <Value>0,4413</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="352">
   <CharCode>ISK</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>10</Nominal> 
   <Name>Èñëàíäñêèõ êðîí</Name> 
   <Value>0,3504</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="398">
   <CharCode>KZT</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>10</Nominal> 
   <Name>Êàçàõñêèõ òåíãå</Name> 
   <Value>0,2906</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="124">
   <CharCode>CAD</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Êàíàäñêèé äîëëàð</Name> 
   <Value>4,2337</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="417">
   <CharCode>KGS</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>10</Nominal> 
   <Name>Êèðãèçñêèõ ñîìîâ</Name> 
   <Value>1,0032</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="156">
   <CharCode>CNY</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Êèòàéñêèé þàíü</Name> 
   <Value>0,6420</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="414">
   <CharCode>KWD</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Êóâåéòñêèé äèíàð</Name> 
   <Value>15,2794</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="428">
   <CharCode>LVL</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ëàòâèéñêèé ëàò</Name> 
   <Value>9,1054</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="440">
   <CharCode>LTL</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ëèòîâñêèé ëèò</Name> 
   <Value>1,8712</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="458">
   <CharCode>MYR</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ìàëàéçèéñêèé ðèíããèò</Name> 
   <Value>1,2881</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="498">
   <CharCode>MDL</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ìîëäàâñêèé ëåé</Name> 
   <Value>0,3932</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="949">
   <CharCode>TRY</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Íîâàÿ òóðåöêàÿ ëèðà</Name> 
   <Value>2,9934</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="578">
   <CharCode>NOK</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Íîðâåæñêàÿ êðîíà</Name> 
   <Value>0,7749</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="586">
   <CharCode>PKR</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>10</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ïàêèñòàíñêèõ ðóïèé</Name> 
   <Value>0,5260</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="985">
   <CharCode>PLN</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ïîëüñêèé çëîòûé</Name> 
   <Value>1,5182</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="682">
   <CharCode>SAR</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ðèàë Ñàóäîâñêîé Àðàâèè</Name> 
   <Value>1,1681</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="810">
   <CharCode>RUB</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>10</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ðîññèéñêèõ ðóáëåé</Name> 
   <Value>1,4814</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="960">
   <CharCode>XDR</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>ÑÄÐ</Name> 
   <Value>6,9556</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="702">
   <CharCode>SGD</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ñèíãàïóðñêèé äîëëàð</Name> 
   <Value>3,1326</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="764">
   <CharCode>THB</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Òàèëàíäñêèé áàò</Name> 
   <Value>0,1314</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="795">
   <CharCode>TMM</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1000</Nominal> 
   <Name>Òóðêìåíñêèõ ìàíàòîâ</Name> 
   <Value>0,3074</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="860">
   <CharCode>UZS</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>100</Nominal> 
   <Name>Óçáåêñêèõ ñóìîâ</Name> 
   <Value>0,2918</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="980">
   <CharCode>UAH</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Óêðàèíñêàÿ ãðèâíà</Name> 
   <Value>0,5313</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="752">
   <CharCode>SEK</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Øâåäñêàÿ êðîíà</Name> 
   <Value>0,6266</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="756">
   <CharCode>CHF</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Øâåéöàðñêèé ôðàíê</Name> 
   <Value>4,2555</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="233">
   <CharCode>EEK</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>1</Nominal> 
   <Name>Ýñòîíñêàÿ êðîíà</Name> 
   <Value>0,4130</Value> 
  </Valute>
 <Valute ID="392">
   <CharCode>JPY</CharCode> 
   <Nominal>10</Nominal> 
   <Name>ßïîíñêèõ èåí</Name> 
   <Value>0,4850</Value> 
  </Valute>
</ValCurs>
```

What do need to do ? Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that you receive strings as CP1252.

Comment: So what property of TIdHTTP under Request do I need to assign it to ?

Comment: CP1252? Doesn't really help, it remains gibberish. Just use http://nbt.tj/?c=4&id=28&lg=en&d=21-02-2011&export=xmlout (`lg=en` sets language to english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the version of `TIdHTTP::Get()` that returns a UTF-16 encoded `UnicodeString`.  That version of `Get()` decodes the raw bytes from the received content's specified charset to UTF-16 (`TIdHTTP` recognizes various XML-based `Content-Type` values, and if detected then it extracts the charset from the XML prolog directly, `windows-1251` in this case, regardless of what the HTTP server said the charset is).  What you are seeing in your `TMemo` are decoded Unicode characters, not the original encoded Ansi octets.

In general, XML should not be treated this way.  Proper byte encoding is important to XML.  You should use the version of `Get()` that downloads the data to a `TStream` instead of a `UnicodeString`.  Then you can use the original undecoded bytes as needed, such as pass them to a real XML parser like `TXMLDocument`, eg:

```
TMemoryStream *XML = new TMemoryStream;
serv->Get("http://nbt.tj/?c=4&id=28&lg=ru&d=13-10-2009&export=xmlout", XML);
XML->Position = 0;
// use XML as needed...
cxMemo1->Text = ReadStringFromStream(XML, Indy8BitEncoding()); 
delete XML;
```

Comment: Remy Lebeau, Thank you very much for your quit detailed answer!!! I'm grateful for your support!!

Answer (score 0):

Try "cp1251" or just "1251" as charset property. Or try using this function:

```
function RussianToUnicode(S: String): String;
var Wrd:Word;
  pW,pR:PWord;
  len:Integer;
begin
  pW:=@S[1];
  len:=Length(S);
  SetLength(Result,len);
  pR:=@Result[1];
  while Len<>0 do begin
    Wrd:=pW^;
    case Wrd of
      $C0..$DF,$E0..$FF:pR^:=Wrd+$0350;
      else pR^:=Wrd;
    end;
    inc(pW);
    inc(pR);
    dec(Len);
  end;
end;
```

Use it like this:

```
text:= RussianToUnicode(IdHTTP.Get('url'));
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it with standard funcs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @remy-lebeau-teamb my problem has been solved!!!

```
 TMemoryStream *XML = new TMemoryStream;
 serv->Get("http://nbt.tj/?c=4&id=28&lg=ru&d=13-10-2009&export=xmlout", XML);
 XML->Position = 0;
// use XML as needed...
 AnsiString s="";
 ReadStringFromStream(XML,s);
 cxMemo1->Text=s;
 delete XML;
```